# Hyper V Server not starting

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, vt-x

I have setup a computer running windows server 2012 Datacenter R2, however after adding the Hyper V Roll I still cannot start a Virtual Machine on the Server. I am told in the error message that the hypervisor is not running, However after checking, It is set to automatically start in BCD 
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`

Furthermore I have also checked that VT-X is enabled in bios and I have been successful in Installing and Starting a VirtualBox VM just to ensure Virtual support was enabled and working.

Has anyone had anything similar to this happen or know what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshoot guide from technet.microsoft? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc742454.aspx